# Showing that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}(\max\{|x_n|,1\})$ defines a norm

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm showing that $$\|x\| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}(\max\{|x_n|,1\})$$ defines a norm when $x \in A$ and $A=F(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$ the vector space formed by $x=(x_1,\dots)$, but I have a slight problem with one of the properties.

For positivity I have that clearly $2^{-n} > 0$ and $\max\{|x_n|,1\} \geqslant 1$. So $\|x\| >0$.

Also for scalar multiplication if $p(x)=\|x\|$ $$p(kx) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}k2^{-n}(\max\{|x_n|,1\}) = k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}(\max\{|x_n|,1\}) =|k|\|x\|$$

The problem comes with the third property that $\|x\|=0 \iff $$x=0$. I just showed that $\|x\| >0$ so this cannot be true?

Answer (score 3):

This not a norm. $\|(\frac 1  2,0,0,..)\|=1$ and $\|4(\frac 1  2,0,0,0...)\|=2+\sum_{n \geq 2} \frac 1 {2^{n}}=\frac  5 2 \neq 4 \|(\frac 1  2,0,0,..)\|$.

You are also right about the fact that $\|x\|\geq \sum 2^{-n}=1$ for all $x$ including $x=(0,0,0,...)$.

Comment: How is the fact that $\|x\|=0 \iff x = 0$ true? It seems that $\|x\| > 0$ always?

Comment: @PedroEstan You are right. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Also I'm not entirely sure that this satisfies the triangle inequality? It would have to be that $$\|x+y\| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}(\max\{|x_n + y_n|,1\}) \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}(\max\{|x_n|,1\}) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}(\max\{|y_n|,1\})$$?

Comment: @Pedro Estan Triangle inequality is true.